# How can I make two concurrent phone calls?

Tags: calls, android-11, google-pixel-6

I use a Google Pixel 6 with Android 11.  How can I make two concurrent phone calls? Goal: calling 2 different numbers in 2 separate calls.

Comment: Are you talking about three-way calling/conferencing calling? Note that it may depend on carrier support.

Comment: @MorrisonChang thanks, trying to call 2 different numbers in 2 separate calls.

Answer (score 1):

You can't from the same number atleast.

A workaround would be this

Install a virtual number provider eg TextNow, 2ndLine 
Now you can make two phone calls simultaneously 
One from your regular SIM and phone app, another one from the virual number provider : BOTH CALLS WOULD BE SEPARATE AND CONCURRENT

Ending note: Though this works, I'm not sure how the microphone permission is gonna be handled